# PHP Slim API returns empty page

Tags: php, sql, pdo, slim

I tried to make an php RestAPI and I have now following Code:

```
$app->get('/api/customers', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `custemers` WHERE 1";
try {
    // Get DatabaseObjects
    $db = new db();
    // Connect
    $db = $db->connect();
    $stmt = $db->query($sql);

    $customers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    $db = null;

    echo json_encode($customers);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":' . $e->getMessage() . '}}';
}});
```

The problem is now, that this returns nothing. If i try `echo 'test';` than comes the string

> test

in the return.

The in the PDO connection are no errors.
The SQL String works fine.

The Head returns

> date: Sat, 17 Feb 2018 15:43:32 GMT
>   server: Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.2.1 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
>   connection: Keep-Alive
>   x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.1
>   content-length: 0
>   keep-alive: timeout=5, max=100
>   content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Can you help me?

EDIT:

Response Status: 200 (OK)

Comment: what does `WHERE 1` condition suppose to mean? And you may have an error in your table name

Comment: You trying to echo Boolean/null value, no wonder you get empty page.

Comment: The spelling in the tablename is correct. I dint changed it. The WHERE 1 is from the SQL from phpmyadmin

Comment: So how can i chage the Boolean/null value?

Comment: Try changing PDO::FETCH_CLASS to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: @NigelRen returns nothing :/

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim yes. its a spelling mistake but its the tablename.

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a question. As a programmer, you are supposed to solve it yourself. Or at least provide an *answerable* question:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for a PDO related problem](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mcve)

Comment: Slimphp is a PSR-7 based micro framework. You should not use echo anymore. Use the $response object instead. Example: `return $response->withJson($customers);`

Comment: I dont know why, but i exported the old table, renamed the table in the SQL-File and imported this as a new table. with the new table (exact the same, only the tablename is changed) it worked fine.